# How to and what responce Client expected from server

Tags: vb6, server-response

My server program in vb6 successfully getting data from client ( Biochemistry analyser operating software). Data came is in duplicates i.e same data again send by client this happen when client give error. " LIS responce timed out". So I think when client is not getting server responce then send data again. Data send was like below

```
MSH|^~\&|Factory|Chemistry Analyzer|||20210430190330||ORU^R01|9|P|2.3.1||||0||ASCII|||
PID|9||||shitalPL||||||||||||||||||||||||||
OBR|1||11|Factory^Chemistry Analyzer|N||20210430183639||||||||Serum|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
OBX|1|NM|GLU|GLU|198.452857|mg/dL|-|Normal|||F||198.452857|20210430183639||||
```

As I get above data. Then what responce I should send to client and How?

Comment: You need to show us the code of your client that retrieves the data. There might be a way to either increase the (most likley default) timeout or retrieve the data in parts, i.e. with multiple client<->server interactions.

Comment: Do you need to tell the client anything?  Have the server respond accordingly.  In other words, when data comes into the server from the client, check whether it exists in your DB.  If the data does exist, you can either ignore the data or update the DB.

Comment: @BrianMStafford: while this does work, that would "only" resolve the symptom _(duplicate data)_, not the cause _(timeouts while retrieving/receiving data)_. To me that's a _"if everything else fails"_ solution, which I personally would try last, after I tried to solve the initial issue and couldn't figure that out.

Comment: Hi Brian, when client (Biochemistry analyser operating software) send data after test completed to the server. Server get ( accepted) that data in textbox then into access db. Meanwhile if there is no responce from server about accepted data then after sometime client again send the same packet of data as above. Currently I solve this by creating cross tab query in access db which do not show duplicate records

Comment: @Hel O'Ween: Agree with you. But my project stuck on this point. Hence I am trying to solve the duplicate data by creating cross tab query and then using it in the project. Please note. Client software is Biochemistry machine operating software that comes with machine and supplied by manufacturer.